# onehotencoder to many indices for array

Tags: python

while running this code i get the error that its to many indices for array. I understand that it is being read as a 1d array and not a 2d array? Ive ran this piece of code using another column z = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values  and it worked perfectly fine.

```
z = dataset.iloc[:, 135].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_z = LabelEncoder()
z[:, 135] = labelencoder_z.fit_transform(z[:,135])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [135])
z = onehotencoder.fit_transform(z).toarray()
```

thanks for any and all help !

Comment: Can you tell us which line this error is coming from? Also, is it perhaps because you need to do `dataset.iloc[:, :135]` instead of `dataset.iloc[:, 135]`? (note the second colon)

Comment: coming from z[:, 135] = labelencoder_z.fit_transform(z[:,135])

i tried the second colon and now i  get error" index 135 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 135" ......errors out at the same line

Comment: ok so z = dataset.iloc[:, 135:136].values  becomes a 2d array that i need for onehotencoder.    then we call z[:, 0]  for the encoder. 

Now i am stuck at the z = onehotencoder.fit_transform(z).toarray() ...it says arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Answer (score 0):

needed to make

```
z = dataset.iloc[:, 135:136].values
```

in order to create a 2d array for onehotencoder. Then z[:, 0] was used to select the column in the new array we created.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('CSV zzsnore.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 14].values
z = dataset.iloc[:, 135:136].values


# Encoding the Independent Variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_z = LabelEncoder()
z[:, 0] = labelencoder_z.fit_transform(z[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
z = onehotencoder.fit_transform(z).toarray()
```